# Can you check if MySql column contains an array of characters?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to implement a search function that allows the user to search by product tag. The problem is some of the tags are in different formats, like some have spaces and others don't.
At the moment I'm using 
`WHERE modelNumber LIKE '" + '%' + number + '%' + "';";`
 This will get me the tag if they only fill in some of the tag name, but this won't work if the tag name includes a space but the user does not enter one. 
My idea was create a char array with the chars in the search, so I'm wondering if there is a way to check if the SQL column entry contains each character in the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note, this is a classic example of SQL injection, best to parameterize, which I recommend you study and understand but this wasn't your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` to check for space characters:

```cs
"abc defg".Contains(' '); // True
```

There is also `Trim`, `TrimEnd`, and `TrimStart` depending on what you are trying to do.